# After 15.10 upgrade, sometimes I have suddendly no more internet connection

Tags: networking, 64-bit, connection, 15.10

After having upgraded to 15.10 from 15.04, it happens randomly, I couldn't yet find a schema.

Sometimes I have no more connection

```
elect@elect-desktop:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

And after a couple of times I tried to force to get a new IP

```
elect@elect-desktop:~$ sudo dhclient -i eth0 
[sudo] password for elect: 
elect@elect-desktop:~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=14.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=13.8 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=15.1 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=12.3 ms
```

And it works as you see, but it is getting boring...

Has anyone experienced something similar?